# Java Split String with Numbers

Tags: java, string, split

How do I split a string with numbers?
Like if I have "20 40" entered, how do I split 
it so I get 20, 40?

```
    int t = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int str = t;
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

My code.

Comment: `String.split` it does not work for an int so you would want to do maybe `String[] nums = x.split("\\s+");`  Im assuming `x` is the `String` of nums divided up by spaces? Look at @Juned Ashan answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to parse a string that contains whitespace-delimited integer tokens, into an `int` array, the following will work:

```
String input = "20 40";
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
int[] numbers = new int[tokens.length];

for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim());
}
```

You can also do this in a one-liner through the `Iterables` and `Splitter` utilities from the amazing [Google Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki):

```
Integer[] numbers = Iterables.toArray(Iterables.transform(
        Splitter.on(' ').trimResults().split(input),
            new Function<String, Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer apply(String token) {
                    return Integer.parseInt(token);
                }
            }), Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to String value and then split, maybe like this:

```
String[] splited = String.valueOf(str).split("\\s+");
```

It seems you are reading the number as String and trying to convert it to integer before the split here:

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

so you can actually split your variable `x` and get the indiviudal int values out of it like this:

```
String[] splited = x.split("\\s+");
for(String num:splited) {
     int intVal = Integer.valueOf(num);
}
```

Comment: `str` is an `int`. How would your solution ever return something other than `new String[] {String.valueOf(str)}`?

Comment: @brimborium String.valueOf() will return the String for the int and split will return the String array ....

Comment: If you are converting an `int` to `String`, there is nothing to split, because it's just a single integer, there will never be a space...

Comment: @brimborium I believe questioner has got a string which he/she tried to convert to int using this  int t = Integer.parseInt(x);

Comment: Thanks, the edit of your answer is much better. The first code segment (the one you initially posted) still does not make sense, because it is equal to what I wrote in my first comment.